# C - Loading function to the data base - Call Stack Error / Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I've been writing a data base in C for some time and yesterday I got an error I can not cope with.
The case is that ,when I was writing loading from .txt function, there were some mistakes after the program read the data from .txt. (f.e. it was "84683-3478- " instead of "1993-5-13")
I tried to change sth and then the crap happened and I've been receiving such error since that time:

"Segmentation fault" -> on Linux
"Call Stack memory" -> on Windows

I don't truly know where the problem is because I didn't change much(the way of putting the text) but crap happened.
I'm pasting the function for you.
Could you help, please?

```
void load(struct player *main)
{
    int bad;
    struct player *act, *prev;    // act- actual prev - previous
    FILE *plik;
    char a;
    char text[l];                 // l=15;
    if((plik = fopen("savings.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No savings\n");
        return;
    }
    if(fgets(text, l, plik) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No saved things\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("These are your savings\n");
    do
    {
        printf("%s", text);
    }while(fgets(text, l, plik) != NULL);
    fclose(plik);
    printf("\nType the name of the file you want to load (with .txt) \n");
    do
    {
        gets(text);         // here program stops, no matter if the name is right or not
        char *text = (char*) malloc(30);
        while (getchar()!='\n')
            continue;
        strcat(text, ".txt");
        printf("%s", *text);
        if((plik = fopen(text, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("There is no such file, type once again \n");
            bad=1;
        }
        else bad=0;
    }while(bad);
    act = main->next;
    while(act != NULL)              //cleaning the actual data base
    {
        prev = act;
        act = act->next;
        free(prev);
    }
    nr_of_players = 0;
    act = main;
    while(fscanf(plik, "%s", act->name)!=0)
    {
        fscanf(plik, "%s", biez->surname);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_y);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_m);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_d);
        fscanf(plik, "%s", biez->position);
        fscanf(plik, "%c", &a);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->nr_cart);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->salary);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->matches);
        act->id = ++nr_of_players;
        act->next = (struct player*) malloc(sizeof(struct player));
        prev = act;
        act = act->next;
    }
    free(act);
    prev->next = NULL;
    fclose(plik);
}
```

Comment: please use proper code indentation, if you want people to read your code.

Comment: Thou shalt not cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: And why are you declaring `text` twice ?

Answer (score 2):

### code review

initialize **all** variables when declaring them

```
void load(struct player *main)
{
    int bad = 0;
    struct player *act = NULL, *prev =  NULL;    
    FILE *plik = NULL;
    char a = '\0';
```

don´t use "l" as a constant it is difficult to distinguish between l and 1 depending on what font used.

```
    char text[l] = {0};                 // l=15;


    if((plik = fopen("savings.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No savings\n");
        return;
    }
```

prefer doing sizeof(text) instead of using "l" here

```
    if(fgets(text, sizeof(text), plik) == NULL)

    printf("\nType the name of the file you want to load (with .txt) \n");
    do
    {
        // here if user puts his elbow on the keyb it crashes the 
        // program use fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) instead.
        gets(text);
```

Never hide a variablename in another scope, use a new variable name

```
        char *mytext = malloc(30); // in C don´t cast malloc
```

Below you are doing strcat on "text" however you just malloc:ed it so there could be anything in the buffer, you should clear the buffer before doing strcat() or use strcpy(_s) / or maybe it was just a typo?

```
        strcat(text, ".txt");
```

A string in C is a sequence of characters, %s says to printf to expect the address of a string of characters ending with \0 but with `*text` you are giving a character value to it, that will not end well.

```
        printf("%s", *text);
```

it is good to have use {} when you can, not just sometimes

```
        if((plik = fopen(text, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("There is no such file, type once again \n");
            bad=1;
        }
        else bad=0;  
    }while(bad);
```

check that "main" points to something proper before using it.

```
    if ( main != NULL )
    {
      act = main->next;
      while(act != NULL)
      {
        prev = act;
        act = act->next;
        free(prev);
      }
    ...
```

here i would suggest you read in the data using fgets() instead and parse the data using sscanf() the way you do it is fragile.

```
    nr_of_players = 0;
    act = main;
    while(fscanf(plik, "%s", act->name)!=0)
    {
        fscanf(plik, "%s", biez->surname);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_y);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_m);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->date_d);
        fscanf(plik, "%s", biez->position);
        fscanf(plik, "%c", &a);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->nr_cart);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->salary);
        fscanf(plik, "%d", &biez->matches);
        act->id = ++nr_of_players;
```

this is unusual, normally you allocate when you find something to put in instead of allocating for the case there may be more to put in.

```
        act->next = malloc(sizeof(struct player));
        prev = act;
        act = act->next;
    }
```

Comment: Also don't name any identifier "main" is C, for obvious reasons. As we can tell from this good code review, the original code _deserves_ bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
char *text = (char*) malloc(30);
while (getchar()!='\n')
  continue;
strcat(text, ".txt");
printf("%s", *text);
```

The last printf should be:

```
printf("%s", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char text[l];                 // l=15;
 .... deleted a bunch of lines ....
do
{
gets(text);         // here program stops, no matter if the name is right or not
char *text = (char*) malloc(30);
while (getchar()!='\n')
  continue;
strcat(text, ".txt");
```

Note that `text[l]` is used for `gets()` - and gets is a BAD function to use, as it doesn't prevent overwriting the end of the input buffer AT ALL. It will just crash (or do something else unexpected).

Instead of `gets()`, use `fgets(stdin, ...)`.

The code als doesn't make sense.

Why are you allocating a new variable called `text` that shadows the `text` you just read something into

If you want a 30 byte string, just create the string with 30 bytes in the first place, rather than 15.

Also, please, please, please don't use variables/constants called `l` or `O` - unless you are entering the "obfuscated C competiton". They look far too much like the digits One and Zero.

Answer (score 0):

`char *text = (char*) malloc(30);`

why are you named it `text`, try some another name, you have already declared `text` at the start of function.

`char text[l];`